# How to create a new object in a c function and pass a reference to it?

Tags: c++, c

**The essence of my question is this:**

What is the best approach for creating a new object in a c function and pass some reference to that new object to the caller?

**My overall setting is a bit more complex and involves mixed c and c++ code, so I am including some background information:**

I am creating a c++ library for a 3D engine.
The library is intended to be used from host applications on different platforms.

For easy compatibility reasons I now intent to hide all c++ code behind an API in plain c.
This works pretty well so far.

The only thing I am not sure about is, which is the best way for actually *creating* my engine instance through my c API.

My first approach was this:

```
// in myEngineAPI.h
void myEngineCreate(void * myEngine);
void myEngineRelease(void * myEngine);


// in myEngineAPI.cpp
#include "myEngineAPI.h"
#include "myPrivateCppEngine.h"

void myEngineCreate(void * myEngine) {
    myEngine = new Engine;               // <- this doesn't seem to work as expected
}
void myEngineRelease(void * myEngine) {
    delete ((Engine *)myEngine);
}


// in my host application
#include "myEngineAPI.h"

void * myEngine = NULL;
myEngineCreate(myEngine);    // <- problem: myEngine is still NULL after this line.

// ...draw some fancy stuff...

myEngineRelease(myEngine);
```

I would expect that `myEngineCreate(void * myEngine)` would assign the address of my newly created object to `myEngine`. But after the function returns, `myEngine` still points to NULL. Why?

Now my second approach was this:

```
// in myEngineAPI.h
void * myEngineCreate();
void myEngineRelease(void * myEngine);


// in myEngineAPI.cpp
#include "myEngineAPI.h"
#include "myPrivateCppEngine.h"

void * myEngineCreate() {
    return new Engine;               // <- ok, the function returns a valid pointer
}
void myEngineRelease(void * myEngine) {
    delete ((Engine *)myEngine);
}


// in my host application
#include "myEngineAPI.h"

void * myEngine = myEngineCreate();  // <- yay, I have a void pointer to my engine

// ...draw some fancy stuff...

myEngineRelease(myEngine);
```

This works. `myEngineCreate()` gives me an opaque pointer to my engine instance, which I can use in my subsequent drawing calls and which I can also hand to my release function that cleans up memory when I'm done with it.
The problem with this approach is, that my profiler complains about a memory leak in `myEngineCreate()`.
I understand that creating an object in one place and owning it in another is a delicate business, and I seem to do something wrong here - but what?

Thanks in advance for any advice or help.

Comment: If you need to work with generics, use `templates` in C++, but avoid `void*` wherever possible! This is error-prone.

Comment: i'm assuming the host application is written in C and myengine in c++, hence the use of void*, as long as you don't forget to call myEngineRelease() the second approach should not be a problem, for the first approach see the answer by Joachim Pileborg below (but of course you still have to delete the object at some point)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lets take your `myEngineCreate` function:

```
void myEngineCreate(void * myEngine) {
    myEngine = new Engine;
}
```

This does not work because `myEngine` is a local variable within the scope of the `myEngineCreate` function. To pass a pointer "by reference" in C you have to pass it as a pointer to a pointer, and use the derefernece operator to assign to the pointer:

```
void myEngineCreate(void ** myEngine) {
    *reinterpret_cast<Engine**>(myEngine) = new Engine;
}
```

And you call it by using the address-of operator `&` of a pointer:

```
void * myEngine;
myEngineCreate(&myEngine);
```

---

As a late addendum, another possible solution is to *return* the new pointer:

```
void* myEngineCreate() {
    retur reinterpret_cast<void*>(new Engine);
}
```

Comment: Although this answer nicely explains why the present code doesn't work, please note that this is not the optimal solution in C, as there is no type safety.

Comment: Right, the first approach works now. Thanks for *pointing* this out. I am nevertheless still getting memory leaks, I'll run some more tests...

Comment: Ok, I fixed my leak. It turned out to be unrelated.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the best approach for creating a new object in a c function and pass some reference to that new object to the caller?

In C, the best, object-orientated way is to create an object of *incomple type*, also known as opaque type (a void pointer is *not* an opaque type, it is just a raw address) .

Example:

// engine.h

```
typedef struct engine_t engine_t;

engine_t* engine_create (void);
```

// engine.c

```
struct engine_t
{
  /* all variables placed here will have true private encapsulation */
};


engine_t* engine_create (void)
{
  return malloc(sizeof(engine_t));
}
```

// main.c

```
int main()
{
  engine_t* my_engine = engine_create();
}
```

This is real object-orientation in C, the best OO you can achieve without C++ language support. The caller will not be able to access any members of the struct.

> But after the function returns, myEngine still points to NULL. Why?

Because pointers themselves are passed by value in C and C++. You either have to pass the address of a pointer or return the pointer to the caller. Multiple questions and FAQ about this topic can easily be found on SO.

Comment: Your answer is the most detailed and gives a lot of interesting details. Nevertheless, I am so far sticking to the void* it seems the simplest solution and I really do not need more right now. Thanks for pointing out the difference between a void pointer and an opaque type.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar using opaque pointers:

```
typedef struct my_c_engine *myCEngine;

extern "C" myCEngine createEngine() {
    return reinterpret_cast<myCEngine>(new myRealEngineClass());
}

extern "C" void releaseEngine(myCEngine c) {
    if(c) {
        myRealEngineClass *x = reinterpret_cast<myRealEngineClass*>(c);
        delete x;
    }
}
```

I did this way because I wanted the C part to be completely isolated.

Comment: I prefer not to hide the pointer syntax behind a typedef, it is confusing to read. Also as a side note: you don't need to check `c` for NULL, no matter if you use new/delete or malloc()/free(). delete and free() both tolerate NULL as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for adding `extern "C"` in your example. I had to add this to my code, too.